# how to display color palette in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, color-scheme, color-picker

Pardon if this is very basic thing but since I am new to it and could not find any thing about it, so I am asking.

I have integrated ckeditor in my textarea but ckeditor is not showing palette to change font color. How can I display it in ckeditor options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you download a [full build of CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo#full)?

What you're looking for is the `colorbutton` plugin. Basic/standard builds of CKE don't have this plugin.